# GitHub Workflow gets triggered twice simultaneously

Tags: github-actions, azure-rm-template

I have a requirement to deploy ARM templates into the Azure Resource Group. The ARM templates are being generated using [creator](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit) tool.

However, whenever the ARM `template.json` and `parameters.json` files are pushed to the repository, the workflow gets triggered twice.

On the trigger section of the workflow, I've tried the below things, but unfortunately, every time the workflow gets triggered twice simultaneously.

1. In this case, as it can't find the parameters file, and hence the deployment fails.

   ```yaml
   on:
     push:
       branches:
         -  'main'
       paths:
         -   'deploy/arm/api-publish-template.json'
   ```
2. In this case, it finds both the `template.json` and `parameters.json` file and hence it triggers the workflow twice.

   ```yaml
   on:
     push:
       branches:
         -  'main'
       paths:
         -   'deploy/arm/*.json'
   ```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have both `push` triggers in one workflow file?

Comment: I don’t have two push triggers. Above I’ve just described two ways I’ve configured the triggers. None of them works as expected. I’ve only one push trigger in my workflow file.

Comment: do you any other triggers for this workflow ?

Comment: No, that's all I've in the trigger `on` section. As every time there are 2 file modifications which happens(template.json and parameters.json), the workflow gets triggered 2 times.